# Python: Functional Composition vs. **kwargs

Tags: python, functional-programming, composition, higher-order-functions

I am confused about the `compose` function in python. From what i've read there are two possible uses:

```
compose(f,g)(x) ~> f(g(x))
```

and

```
compose(f,g, unpack=True)(x) ~> f(*g(x))
```

the latter being used in

```
def f(a,b):
  return a + b
def g(x):
  return [x,x]
```

so that above code will result in

```
compose(f,g, unpack=True)(x) ~> f(*g(x)) ~> f(x,x).
```

> **Now for the question:** How do I handle keywords in this context?

More specifically the compose functions seems to work only properly for functions with signature

```
def f(*args):
    ...
def g(*args):
    ...
```

Take for example the function call

```
f(4,5, extra = some_info).
```

Is it possible to write this as a composite via compose? If so, `g` should have **unpacked output** in the form of

```
***g(x) = 4,5,extra=some_info(x).
```

Comment: A possible solution might be to enhance the `compose` function so that it accepts a third option for `unpack` and then `g` would have to give output like `[args, kwdict]` where args is a list and kwdict a dictionary.